# PHP Comparisons with multiple conditions

Tags: php, comparison, logic, comparison-operators

Is it right to write this ?

```
 if($site!=1 || $site!=4)
```

I want to execute a code if the site ID isn't 1 or 4.
Two negations are possible with a OR? Because it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you using `||` if any of them satisfies it will be executed. When you dont want the both should be satisfied the you need to use `&&`. Should be -

```
if($site!=1 && $site!=4)
```

It will check the both conditions, i.e. `$site` is not equals to `1` or `4`.

OR you can use `in_array` -

```
if(!in_array($site, array(1, 4)))
```

Currently it will check `$site` is `1` or not first, if it is not it will go inside the condition and ignore the rest of the conditions. So for `4` it will not be checked.

Comment: Ok thanks, but in my head it was in two different cases : site1 or site4. And with && the two conditions must be executed. But it works thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Although you already have a correct answer, you can also use

```
if (!in_array($site,array(1,4)))
```

This simplifies it if there are a lot of numbers to check against. This is even simpler in PHP 5.4+

```
if (!in_array($site,[1,4]))
```

Comment: It is also a good trick. Help a lot if many values needed to be checked. :)